# Leer archivo dentro de JAR

Tags: java, jar

Una vez que genero mi archivo .jar necesito ingresar al archivo para ubicar la siguiente carpeta, ya me genera la ruta donde se entra el archivo.
Ahore necesito leer el archivo para que se ejecute el instalador de mysql-utilities.

```
aplicacion.exec("cmd.exe /k "
                            + new File(InstalarApps.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI())
                                    .getAbsolutePath()
                            + "\\aplicativos\\mysql-utilities-1.6.5-winx64.msi");
```

Cuando compilo el proyecto en eclipse no hay problema si encuentra la ruta y me abre el instalador del MSQL, el problema sucede cuando genero mi .jar no ejecuta el instalador.